# coordinates from google placesautocomplete and google maps are different

Tags: android, google-maps, placeautocompletefragment

I use [Google Place Autocomplete Widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) to select place. It works well when i display the selected place on a map in my app. But, the problem is the coordinates I get from places autocomplete widget is different from the one we get from google map. For example, the coordinates of place called 'Kannur, Kerala' is **11.874477499999998, 75.37036619999999** in autocomplete widget and in google map is **11.8744801,75.3692719**. I use the following code to get the coordinates from widget:

```
Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(context, data);
LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
```

Also, when I open the google map navigation intent from my app, it shows the following error:
[image]

I use the following code to open navigation intent:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + latitude+ ", " + longitude + "(" + pickupPointName + ")");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Is there any way to make both coordinates same?

Comment: I'm wondering how you figured out that coordinate on Google Maps is 11.8744801,75.3692719? Can you explain steps to get this coordinate?